# Amazon S3 multiple object delete using aws or boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I would like to try amazone feature  [delete multiple object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html) but using 
boto or aws.

How can I lanuch a POST request using boto or aws ??
Below is the stuff I wanna try :

```
POST /?delete HTTP/1.1
Host: bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com
Authorization: authorization string
Content-Length: Size
Content-MD5: MD5

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Delete>
    <Quiet>true</Quiet>
    <Object>
         <Key>Key</Key>
         <VersionId>VersionId</VersionId>
    </Object>
    <Object>
         <Key>Key</Key>
    </Object>
    ...
</Delete>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Boto provides support for MultiDelete.  Here's an example of how you would use it:

```
import boto.s3
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1')  # or whatever region you want
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
keys_to_delete = ['mykey1', 'mykey2', 'mykey3', 'mykey4']
result = bucket.delete_keys(keys_to_delete)
```

The result will provide information about which delete operations were successful and which, if any, failed.  If you want the `Quiet` mode which tells you only about failures, pass in `quiet=True` to the `delete_keys` call.

Comment: is it using the Multi delete features or is it doing it in using a for loop?

Comment: The ``delete_keys`` method in boto uses the MultiDelete feature of S3.

Comment: Is there an update of this answer for Boto3?

Comment: Didn't find the `delete_keys` method in the documentation, but there is a `delete_objects` function that works similarly.